# What's unclear about this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

It's not clear to me what's unclear about this question: [How to block OpenProcess or WriteProcessMemory for my process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041629/).

The person provided the same question in both the title and the body:

```
How to block OpenProcess or WriteProcessMemory for my process?
```

I think the folks on Stack Overflow incorrectly closed the question because they objected to why he was trying to do it.

I don't believe there was anything ambiguous about what he is asking. But I've done it before myself, so I might have some insight into the issue. I also provided the code I use in my projects. Its non-trivial, and it would be nice if it was available to others who have the same concerns.

The question potentially *could* have been closed as too broad since the code is non-trivial. However, the community did not make that observation (apparently no one commenting has written that code). Plus, the question has an answer with the code so its hard to complain about that now.

Is there anything that can be done to help the poster? He's new to the site, and it would be nice if this did not apply: [Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users).

Comment: The comments below the question seem to indicate there is enough room for clarification.

Comment: @Bart - In the context the author provided (effectively DRM), its irrelevant. He *does not* want *his* process opened. Its does not matter where its coming from.

Comment: @jww C'mon, are you serious?

Comment: @jww Sounds like you're simply choosing one interpretation based on what you assume the OP wants.  That doesn't make the question unclear, as that clarifying information should be in the question, rather than forcing readers to make a lot of assumptions about what is actually being asked.

Comment: If you think that the question is too broad then why did you answer it?

Comment: @Servy - there's no interpretation. The OP clearly asked "How to block OpenProcess or WriteProcessMemory for my process?". There's only one documented way to do it on Windows. If you have any other documented ways, then please share.

Comment: @ Servy - I did not think it was too broad. I have experience with the subject matter, and I knew exactly what the answer was.

Comment: @Servy - but you did not answer the question. What exactly, is unclear about the question?

Comment: @jww The actual intent of the author is unclear, as the comments are discussing.  It seems that pretty much all of the readers feel that the literal question that he asked isn't really want he wants to have.  Spending a whole bunch of time answering a question that doesn't actually represent the problem at hand, and that doesn't actually solve that problem, is just wasting the time of everyone involved.

Comment: @Servy - That's tenuous at best. The author asked a clear question, and theres no reason to try and figure out an intent. That reasoning would make ***every*** question on Stack Overflow off-topic. Hell, I might read that someone is asking if little green men exist on Mars. Or you might argue my question is about little green men on Mars. Its a ridiculous leap.

Comment: @jww: But "spending a whole bunch of time answering a question that doesn't actually represent the problem at hand, and that doesn't actually solve that problem, is just wasting the time of everyone involved"  is not a ridiculous leap.  It happens all the time.

Comment: @jww So you think that there's no indication in the question that he's looking to actually prevent the memory of his process from being manipulated, rather than merely to trap these two method calls?  Because your answer clearly shows the opposite.  Your answer goes into detail about different ways of accessing memory, different possible malicious behaviors to be dealt with, etc.  You simply made assumptions about what the actual problem was, and used that as the basis of your answer, more or less ignoring the literal question asked.

Comment: @Servy - *"You simply made assumptions..."* - I did not make any assumptions. I simply answered his question.

Comment: @jww You made all *sorts* of assumptions about the question.  That's not necessarily a bad thing, but not even recognizing that you're making them most certainly is a serious problem. The vast majority of your answer isn't even talking about any of the points in the question; it's explaining entirely separate problems that he needs to worry about and then attempting to solve them. How is that *not* making assumptions? It looks like a rather small percentage of your answer is actually answering the question that was asked; most of it appears to be answering what you think his real problems are.

Comment: @Servy - again, no assumptions were made. I answered his question. That was easy because I knew the two privileges that corresponded to calls. Then I provided additional insight into how the implementation could fail to meet expectations. I provided the additional insight so he would be aware of the risk.

Comment: @jww And that is making assumptions.  It's making assumptions about the actual problem, that this information is relevant, etc.  None of that information is in the question, which means that you *assumed* all of that information.  It sounds like you don't know what an assumption actually is...

Comment: @Servy - well, this is going nowhere. You, and others who feel like you, should visit the answer, downvote it and flag it as NAA. Better, flag it for moderator attention and use a description like *"he answered the question the poster asked, and not the question I believe the poster intended"*. You should also flag the question for deletion. Use something like *"the poster asked the question he asked, and not the question I believe he intended"*. Here's the question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26041629/608639, and here's the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26042372/608639.

Comment: @jww You're the one saying that all that's relevant is the literal question that is asked, that we shouldn't be inquiring as to what the actual problem is, etc.  My point, that you apparently can't understand, is that your own answer is doing everything that your meta comments are saying shouldn't be done.

Comment: @Servy - its part of a comprehensive answer. While you are busy flagging, you should flag my answer to the question before this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26031693/608639. It was also comprehensive. And the one before that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26030350/608639. I'm pretty much a sitting duck...

Comment: @jww Yes, and to make that comprehensive answer you were forced to make all sorts of assumptions (despite refusing that you've made them).  Other people wanted to ensure that the question itself actually contained enough information to write a quality answer without needing to make all sorts of assumptions.  When a question doesn't contain enough information to post a quality answer without making a whole lot of assumptions we use the close reason "unclear" to indicate that the question needs to provide more information.  You just choose to guess instead.

Comment: None of the interaction that is currently visible on that question is "not nice" or "abusive". (Perhaps there are comments that have been deleted, I don't know.) Please stop thinking of question closure as somehow offensive.

Comment: Also, one of the most helpful things one can do for a new user is to demonstrate, by editing, what a great Stack Overflow question should look like. Your edit stops pretty short; fixing the grammar would have been an easy additional step.

Comment: @Josh Caswell - perhaps I don't appreciate your sensibilities.... but what is so cordial about -10 votes on a clear and concise question with a brief context? If you guys applied the same criteria to other questions (many of which are arguably worse), then the site would close millions of questions today (perhaps 10's of millions). Also, the grammar does not bother me. I don't persecute ESLs. If it bothers you, then you should move to fix it.

Comment: What?! Editing for grammar _is not_ persecution. That's a seriously weird view. Good grammar makes the question more useful for everybody who sees it (not to mention acting as ESL _instruction_ for the OP). People usually use downvotes to indicate that they don't think a question is useful. Some voters thought that such a terse, un-researched, and (as they judged -- I know you don't agree) unclear question would not be useful to others.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61937/discussion-on-question-by-jww-whats-unclear-about-this-question).

Comment: @Robert - sorry, I don't use chat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already did help the poster by answering his question.

Closing is sometimes a judgment call.  But once a question has been adequately answered (within the context of the question that was asked), whether the question remains open or not should be irrelevant to the asker.

Good answers don't necessarily redeem bad questions.  That said, I don't see anything particularly wrong with the question at hand.  I think people don't like it because it contains some invalid assumptions, one of which is that his protection scheme is actually going to work.  But that's not what he asked.  He asked how to do something, and he asked it in a way which should be well within the scope of a Q&A.

A good answer would describe how to do it, and then explain why it's not a good idea.

Comment: I don't care if I get downvoted for disagreeing with the community. It happens often, and I have a lot of fans. However, I take exception when new users are abused. That poor fellow did not deserve that treatment from the community. If the members of the community don't feel like answering or don't know the answer, then they should simply move on.

Comment: I looked again, but I don't see much abuse there.  People need to stop thinking of downvotes and close votes as abusive, unless they are being used in an abusive way.  Sure, you thought the question was perfectly clear, but it's the user community that makes that determination, not any one person.

Comment: @jww You think informing him that his question lacks details, providing constructive comments to help determine what it is that he's really asking, attempting to avoid answers to the question until it has been adequately clarified, and pointing to some outside resources that can help him understand the gravity of the question that he's asking is treatment that he didn't deserve?  A number of people (besides you) spend time trying to help him out.  Informing him (constructively) that his question is currently lacking and needs improvement is an important part of that process.

Comment: @jww _"If the members of the community don't feel like answering or don't know the answer, then they should simply move on"_. You're absolutely right. And, by extension, if they don't feel it's appropriate for the site, they should vote to close it. That's how the system is designed to work; people earn privileges as they get more involved (and thus more familiar) with how the site operates, and they're free to exercise their judgement with those privileges. The (small) majority just happen to disagree with you about this question

Comment: @Servy - *"you think informing him that his question lacks details..."* - his question does not lack detail. He provided context and asked a clear and concise question. I apologize (for him and myself) that its not the question you {hoped|wished} he would have asked.

Comment: @jww You only don't feel that the question lacks detail because you made a whole pile of assumptions when answering the question.  Rather than asking the OP to clarify his question with enough information to answer it, you just made a whole lot of guess as to what he was doing and answered based on all of those assumptions.  That's a very strong sign that the question *is* lacking in detail.  The fact that you don't care that you had to make a whole bunch of assumptions to answer the question doesn't mean that it's not lacking in detail.

Comment: @Servy - again, I did not make any assumptions. First, I answered his question. Then, I provided additional information based on the context he provided. No assumptions were necessary. As someone with subject matter expertise, I did not need to make no assumptions. Apparently, those who lacked the expertise assumed some assumptions (???).

Comment: @jww I've already explained to you what assumptions you've made.  Just saying that you didn't make them doesn't make it true.  Having subject matter expertise doesn't mean you didn't make assumptions, it means that your assumptions are more likely to be correct, and that you're more likely to be able to make assumptions in the first place.  A correct assumption is still an assumption.  You seem to have only confirmed to me that you don't actually understand what an assumption actually is.

Comment: @ Servy - like I said, I made no assumption. I answered based on the information provided in the question, and the question itself. If my answer did not thoroughly answer his question and address some of the issues related to the context provided, then you should flag it for removal.

Comment: @jww If the question is clear to you, but apparently not clear to other intelligent people who have voted to close it, then perhaps the better solution would be for you to *edit the question*. If you get it, you're in the best position to make it more clear for everyone else. That's far more productive than arguing about it on Meta. Honestly, I could go either way on this. I probably wouldn't have voted to close it, but in its current state, I wouldn't vote to re-open either. You can change that.